# Team Foundation Server 2010: How to enable reports?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-reports

Having installed the "Team Foundation Server - Standard Edition"; but no reports/reporting are available in the VS "Team Explorer" under my collection/project.

Can I assuming that it's the "Reporting Application Tier" that I need to configure in the  TFS2010 Administration Console?  And in that case I should create som TFS_* databases?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the solution were to uninstall/reinstall all.

The secret is to bang the rocks together guys :)

But for others: Remember to have the user for TFS being a member of your domain, to complete and configure the SQL including Reporting and Sharepoint BEFORE installing TFS

For some, it's also advisable to enable TCP/IP protocol in SQL before anything else.

And finally: Some of the reports on a freshly installed TFS2010 does now work, but have patience in around ½ day, since there are jobs that have not yet run...

/René